# open_basedir loose it interest with a parent folder?

Tags: php, directory, parent, open-basedir

I use open_basedir with the ini_set function. I want to restrict it to a specific directory like this

```
__DIR__ . '/my_directory';
```

So like this it works! I can't include the parent folder with this include

```
include "../parent/my_file.php";
```

But if I use this

```
include include __DIR__ . '../parent/my_file.php';
```

I can access to the parent folder despite I have an open_basedir active.

When I get all included files I can see my parent folder included like this :

```
"/my_directory/../parent/my_file.php
```

So I think PHP understands them like a folder and don't see that it's the parent folder. I am right?

Do you know if there is a solution to this problem? Because I need to restrict the include to my specific folder and I don't want to go higher in the hierarchy.

PS. I'm a newbie on SO. I hope it was understandable! 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even when specifying open_base_dir in PHP, there is several commands that can bypass this if they are enabled (like  `system()` )

You should make sure that your Apache (or other webserver) configuration also limits the user to a certain root.

The default open_basedir restrictions for shared Linux hosting accounts have no value. PHP scripts can access all directories within your hosting account.

If your apache config has:
`php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/vhosts/httpdocs"`
than this will override you php settings.

Please create a file to check phpinfo like this and verify what the setting is there:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Comment: So if I want that my php files doesn't include php file in a parent folder how can I do this ? Because currently with phpinfo I have an empty open_basedir.

Comment: You can set this in your php.ini fiile